# Which port does ProxyServlet.Transparent listen to?

Tags: proxy, jetty, port

I want to use `ProxyServlet.Transparent` jetty proxy to redirect requests to another server. What port should the client use to send http requests so that they will be intercepted by ProxyServlet.Transparent?

Is there a way to set this port?

Answer (score 0):

ProxyServlet is just a simple servlet running in Jetty. The port jetty listens to is configured in the connector's configuration.

In the standard distribution you'll find the port configs in start.ini:

jetty.port=8080
jetty.https.port=8443
jetty.spdy.port=8443

Depending on which connector you use, uncomment and change the desired port setting.

Always good to consult the documentation on such issues:
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-connectors.html#jetty-connectors